# How can I make a click on a DIV submit my form using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following HTML:

```
<form action="/User/Account/LogOff" id="logoutForm" method="post">
   <button class="float-left submit-button" title="Logoff">Logoff</button>
</form>
```

I would like to replace this with:

```
<form action="/User/Account/LogOff" id="logoutForm" method="post">
   <div class="button" id="logout" title="Logout">
      <span>Logout</span>
   </div>
</form>
```

Is there a way that I can catch a click on the div#logout and use this as a submit for the form? I saw this for a link:

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Logout</a>
```

But how could I do it for a DIV like mine?

Comment: just use a submit button if you are not use any client side validation .that's good don't use unnecessary js ,for logout you dosent even want a form .it can be a link

Comment: You can try the solution in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366087/submit-data-on-div-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this into your DIV:

```
   <div class="button" id="logout" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit();" title="Logout">
```

EDIT 1:
Thanks for pointing out.

```
   <div class="button" id="logout" onclick="submitForm()" title="Logout">
```

Javascript:

```
 function submitForm()
 {
      document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit();
 }
```

Comment: Don't put `javascript:` prefix in `onXXX` attributes. That's only needed for `href` links.